# Gson: need to serialize integer zeros but exclude other nulls

Tags: java, serialization, gson

What is most simple way to chieve following?:
I want serialize integer values no matter zero or non-zero, but I also want exclude other(non-int) nulls.
If I use this approach

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

then I serialize both integer zeros and other null (not what I need).

---

Probably, I need to clarify the question. For example if I have a class

```
class SomeClass {
    private int shift;
    private SomeClass2 additionalData; 
}
```

So, I want to serialize this class object having int fields always been shown even if it is zero, but additionalData should be shown only if it is not null.

Comment: What does '*other* nulls' mean? Zero isn't a null.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I solved the issue: the point was to explicitly set int field to 0 , otherwise(non-initialized) it was treated as null: Either skiped(if serializeNulls() is no used), or encoded as "null"